# RequestMapping doesn't work, 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know, there are a lot of such questions, but I've read all of the answers and they didn't help me.

I become 404 error all the time I try to get my jsp from controller.

My web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

(I tried to use just one `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` too, it didn't help.)

My dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="olegshan.agg.jba.controller"/>

</beans>
```

My IndexController.java:

```
package olegshan.agg.jba.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp";
    }
}
```

When I type into my address line, for example, `http://localhost:8080/index.html` it doesn't work, I become 404.

I still can't rich my index.jsp even by typing direct in address line `http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp` — I become 404 error.

I can rich the files from my web folder, for example `http://localhost:8080/hello.jsp` and it works OK. But when I ask my Controller method to return this file as following: `return "/hello.jsp";`it still doesn't work.

I use Spring 4.2.5, Tomcat 8.0.33, Intellij Idea 2016.1.1.

Please, help me.

Comment: The address should be http://localhost:8080/index right? Or your @RequestMapping("/index") should be @RequestMapping("/index.html")

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure view resolver too.
Read this: http://blog.mikeski.net/java-web-development/part-4-spring-controller-and-view-view-resolver

Comment: If you not configure view resolver, Spring will use InternalResourceViewResolver. See it's source code to look up default suffix and prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And type in your browser something like your @RequestMapping, example `http://localhost/your_context/hello`

Furthermore, one time the request will into the controller, the view should be handle by one viewResolver.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

Then, in your Controller, just need this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public String index(){

    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I have another problem — java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

And Tomcat doesn't start at all.

Comment: Add the spring-web,jar in your pom. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web

Comment: I've read, that this problem may be caused by spring-web, but it is there from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, it waw in pom.xml — I forgot that: `<packaging>war</packaging>`

So my code is correct.

Thank you all for trying to help me.